# How to use Retrofit with RxJava when the status code is 400 to get me the error message?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I used Retrofit with RxJava like this：

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(HttpURL.BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

and when the request error, such as password is wrong, the status code is 400, and the error msg will int the errorBoby to get me just like {code: 1000, message: "password is wrong"}.

However, the gons GsonConverterFactory will not fromJson in respone.getErrorBody , so I change my code just like this

```html
 Call<Result<User>> call = ApiManger.get().getLoginApi().login1(login);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<Result<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result<User>> call, Response<Result<User>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 0) {
                    mLoginView.onLoginSuccess(response.body().getData());
                } else {
                    try {
                        Result result = new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),Result.class);
                        ToastUtils.showShort(result.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result<User>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

so it can not be used with Rxjava, how can I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using Rx and here is how:

```
mSubscription.add(mDataManager.login(username, password)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                if (NetworkUtil.isHttpStatusCode(e, 400) || NetworkUtil.isHttpStatusCode(e, 400)) {
                                    ResponseBody body = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();
                                    try {
                                        getMvpView().onError(body.string());
                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        Timber.e(e1.getMessage());
                                    } finally {
                                        if (body != null) {
                                            body.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(User user) {
                              //TODO Handle onNext
                            }
                        }));
            }
```

NetworkUtil

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    /**
     * Returns true if the Throwable is an instance of RetrofitError with an
     * http status code equals to the given one.
     */
    public static boolean isHttpStatusCode(Throwable throwable, int statusCode) {
        return throwable instanceof HttpException
                && ((HttpException) throwable).code() == statusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a try and i think your answer looks great

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialise the error body string first

try something like this in your onNext():

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    JSONObject errorBody = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
    String message = errorBody.getString("message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its usually a better idea to accept the response in a standard format -

```
Class Response{
    int code;
    String message;
    Data data; //////now data is the actual data that u need

    /////getter setters
    }
```

Now add an api method like this -

```
@GET("api_name")
    Observable<Response> getResponse(Params);
```

now call `retrofit.getResponse(params)` and you will get the observable, subscribe to that observable and check its value in `onNext` and implement your logic. So in your case(password error) the data would be null, but you will have code and message.